# Can we test SIRIKit extensions in IOS Simulator :

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, siri

I am trying to develop an app extension using sirikit, but when i am trying to run it on simulator iphone 7plus, it is giving the following error :-

**SpringBoard was unable to service the request.**

Can anyone please tell me whether IOS Simulator support SIRIKit extension or not !

Comment: Support has been added, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43364544/456434

Comment: Yes  its available you can check updated answer below  with screenshots

Answer (score 19):

**Edit**

For Xcode 8.3 or above you will be able to use Siri in Simulator. The steps are -

**1) Enable Siri from the settings of Simulator.**

**2) From the Hardware select Siri**

Here are some images for reference -

**Step 1 -**

[image]

**Step 2 -**

[image]

**Step 3 -**

[image]

**Step 4 -**

### [image]

***Outdated Answer***

No you can't do that in Simulator

Check this

> To run and debug your Intents extension on a device Select the build
>   scheme for your Intents extension. When you add an Intents extension
>   to your project, Xcode automatically creates a build scheme for
>   running that extension. Configure the scheme to run on an attached
>   device. **You cannot debug your Intents extension in the simulator.**
>   Select Product > Run to launch your extension on the device. When
>   prompted by Xcode, select Siri (or Maps) as the app to run. Xcode
>   builds your app and extension, installs them on the device, and
>   launches the app you selected.

Reference - [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/CreatingtheIntentsExtension.html)

Comment: It's important to select the right Audio Input Source. For checking that: Hardware -> Audio Input

Answer (score 8):

In Xcode 9 you can test Siri tasks by UI Tests. They talk about it in the end of [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/228/) WWDC session. 
Basically it looks kinda like this:

```
    let siri = XCUIDevice.shared.siriService
    siri.activate(voiceRecognitionText: "How many points are on my credit card?")
    let predicate = NSPredicate {(_, _) -> Bool in
        sleep(5)
        return true
    }

    let siriResponse = expectation(for: predicate, evaluatedWith: siri, handler: nil)
    self.wait(for: [siriResponse], timeout: 10)
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes  update  your XCode Version :8.3.1 and above support SIRI in simulator.

**STEP-1 :**

[image]

**STEP-2**
Enable SIRI from Settings in Simulator

**STEP-3**
Hardware--->SIRI

[image]

Comment: had to download a preview version of XCode 8.3.2 see https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12

Answer (score 3):

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/CreatingtheIntentsExtension.html) say:

> You cannot debug your Intents extension in the simulator.

Update: This has changed in Xcode 8.3.

Comment: Adding URL to the Doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/CreatingtheIntentsExtension.html

Comment: Oh I am sorry, didn't notice it over there.

Answer (score 2):

Now You can use in Xcode 8.3.1

[PREVIOUS ANSWER]

According to the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/CreatingtheIntentsExtension.html)

No, you can't

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Xcode 8.3 you can invoke Siri using Hardware > Siri after enabling Siri in the Settings app on Simulator.